# Accessing specific parameter from parameter pack inside function scope, how?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given,

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void foo(T t, Args ...args){/*foo scope*/}
```

When `foo("bar",27,true);` is called, how to access `true`, within the scope of foo?
Can a parameter simply be extracted like `auto param3=args<2>;`?
I'm trying to get both the parameter type and the value it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) creates a tuple of lvalue references. Paired with [`std::get<I>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) will give you access to the arguments as if they were referred by name.

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    auto args = std::tie(t, ts...);
    auto param3 = std::get<2>(args);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6014e140bc4c814e)

Note: Usually, one would also be interested in retaining and restoring the value categories of parameters passed by forwarding references. For that [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) is a better choice.

Comment: Why did we use `std::tie()` with `t` as its first parameter? When it's removed, index begins at second parameter. Can you explain also the logic please?

Comment: @Xemdocia It's your choice.

Comment: If it's called like `auto args=std::tie(ts...);` then `std::get<0>(args);` returns 2nd parameter, not the first. This I don't understand, can you explain? Why does `t` fix the indexing?

Comment: @Xemdocia Tuples are index from `0`. For the call `foo("bar", 27, true)`, `t="bar"` and `ts...` becomes `27, true`. Together, `t, ts...`, becomes `"bar", 27, true`, with indices, `0, 1, 2`, respectively. Without `t` you will have indices `0, 1` for `27`, and `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much